# how to execute events in symfony?

Tags: symfony, events, search, datepicker, capture

I am new to symfony and I would like to capture the events of the following elements, where and how could I do it?

```
  <div class="search-container">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
  
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    {% for s in servicios %}
     <option value={{s.idservicio}}>{{ s.nombre  }}</option> 
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <div class="datepicker">
      <input id="startDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
      <p>a</p>
      <input id="endDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
  </div>
```

what i am trying to do is that when i type something in the search or select a date for example and it makes me a new search with the ones i have selected or entered. with javascript i would use ajax but here i am using twig and php.

thank you

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you mean listening to events on your datepicker and doing something in javascript ?

Comment: what i am trying to do is that when i type something in the search or select a date for example and it makes me a new search with the ones i have selected or entered. with javascript i would use ajax but here i am using twig and php.

Comment: Well you can still have ajax in your twig or if you use webpack encore in an asset file with your javascript

Comment: with twig and php couldn't it be done?

Comment: The only way to do something dynamic in your webpage is using javascript. PHP Is just server side. You do have html in your twig don't you ? So you can also have javascript ? Which then could do your ajax request ?